# Automation error on VB6 - "The specified module cannot be found" - 2147024770

Tags: excel, vb6, excel-2010

I have a VB6 program that uses Excel application to populate the data. The program works on my machine but when I run this on server I am getting automation error:

[image]

When I rerun the executable in the server again for the second time it works fine. Both the machines have Excel 2003 and Excel 2010.

Error occurs in this line:

```
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange. but you can try creating the object twice...

```
On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
On Error Goto 0

If xlApp is Nothing Then
  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If
```